# VBA check if search value is something

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a macro to add and remove clients to a database. I want to be able to stop if the client exists in the database, and continue if it does not. The following works if the client already exists:

```
Dim newClient As String, foundRange As Range
newClient = Sheets("Summary").Range("K2").Value

'check if client exists

Set foundRange = Sheets("Per Client").Cells.Find(what:=newClient, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)

If foundRange = newClient Then
    MsgBox "Client " & newClient & " already exists."
    GoTo finishUp
End If

'add new client
'code continues here'
```

At present if the client does exist, then `foundRange` does equal `newClient`, and the user gets the message, and the macro jumps to `finishUp`. However if `foundRange = Nothing`, I get the

```
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

error.

This is the only time `foundRange` is callled in the macro. What is the best way to solve this, should `foundRange = Nothing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foundRange` will indeed equal `Nothing` if no cells are found.

You could check for this as follows:

`If Not foundRange is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Client " & newClient & " already exists."
    GoTo finishUp
End If`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out using `If Not Nothing`:

```
If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Client " & newClient & " already exists."
    GoTo finishUp
End If
```